# how pass variables by arrays not db records?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I'm currently building a data generator. First I want to implement is PESEL (kind of personal ID in Poland based on birth date) generator - I want to enter in form a temporary data with start and end birth date interval - I don't want to store it in database (or I should I do it?) 
Here is my pesel controller:

```
  def new
    @pesel = Array.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @pesel }
    end
  end
```

but I've got an "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class" error - is it a good way anyway of solvint this case? I read somewhere that using temporary variables is not with 'The Ruby Way' - if my solution is wrong, please suggest the correct one. (e.g pass this vars through cookies? hash? helper method?)

here is the stacktrace(I think):

```
Started GET "/pesel" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-05 16:18:20 +0100
  Processing by PeselController#new as HTML
Rendered pesel/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1513.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1793ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):
    1: <%= simple_form_for @pesel do |f| %>
    2:   <%= f.input :date_of_birth, :as => :date, :start_year => Date.today.year - 90,
    3:                                 :end_year => Date.today.year - 12, :discard_day => true,
    4:                                 :order => [:month, :year] %>
  app/views/pesel/new.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_pesel_new_html_erb__708648673_90148530'
  app/controllers/pesel_controller.rb:7:in `new'

Rendered /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (5.6ms)
Rendered /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (4.0ms)
Rendered /home/ofca/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (17.6ms)
```

Comment: You'll need to give us a bit more about this error. Can you give us the full stacktrace? This usually tells us which line of code is actually breaking - which helps a lot. Also - it's telling you that there's a nil somewhere important. Somewhere that there shouldn't be a nil. Have a think about what might be causing this.

Comment: Check http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Struct.html it can simplify building a model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_for` assumes certain properties exist for the object you pass it, such as `model_name`.

1. Instead of using `form_for @pesel`, just use [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) and the related `_tag` methods.
2. Use a Pesel model. Models are *not* tables, and your model doesn't have to write anything to the database. Just don't inherit from ActiveRecord, but do provide a `model_name` and any other fields the `form_for` helper expects.